Changing the background of a bootstrap 3 tab
I have a table id="sigTable which is dynamically generated with the results of a query using jQuery and dataTables.
I also have a TABBED menu written using bootstrap 3.
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab-today">
      <table name="timeline" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped" id="signageTable" width="100%" data-role="datatable" data-info="false">
        <tr class="ColHeader">
        </tr>
        <tbody class="CurrentSignage-rows">
          <div class="inline-header-elements">
            <input id="clear-checkboxes" type="checkbox">
            <label for="clear-checkboxes">Clear all</label>
            <div class="display-options">
              L (Landscape), P (Portrait), I (Small Displays), D (Default Image)
            </div>
          </div>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-planned">
      <table name="timelineahead"  id="signageTableAhead" 
            border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped"width="100%" data-role="datatable" data-info="false">
        <thead>
          <tr class="CenterHeaderSignageData"> </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="CurrentSignage-rows"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-buttons" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
  <div class="TabButtonDiv">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs custom" role="tablist" id="navTab">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab-today" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">Today</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-planned" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">Planned</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-new" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">
          <button id="newSelectedButton" class="tab-btn-edit" data-tab="tab1">New Promotion</button>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-edit" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">
          <button id="editSelectedButton" class="tab-btn-edit" data-tab="tab1">Edit Selected</button>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

What I need to do is when a row of data is selected from the dataTables table, change the background colour in the tab with an id of editSelectedButton
I have tried using the code below but that did not work
$('#sigTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $('#editSelectedButton a').css('color', '');
  } else {
    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#editSelectedButton a').css('color', 'red'); 
  }
});

Can anyone help?

We are missing the main part of your HTML. Your js selection starts on id=sigTable. Where is it ?

@Mister Jojo
where am I using a # in the HTML ?

@Mister Jojo
My mistake typo, I have corrected the text. Thanks

@G-Cyrillus
I have added more of the HTML if that helps

this is because your HTML is invalid, you must use a validator like the  w3c validator to correct all your errors.

if the table is not there when the dom is ready $('#sigTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() { will not work as a selector

Hi all, I have fixed my issue. Many thanks for all the down votes and no constructive help.

Removed the  from the tab items and used the id of the tab.
